# How to keep each item (form) state that populates by ListView.builder()

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, flutter-provider

I have a `ListView.builder()` that populates the `Cards` widget based on the length of the list I provide (the list is infinity). When the user clicks on each `Card()`, a form will pop up, and the user can fill out the form. the form data saved in provider class variables. The reason I use `Provider` instead of `setState()` is to keep the data persistent even when the form is closed and reopened.

My question is how to keep each form separate.